# Setting up Django Channels

Tags: django, django-channels

I have been trying to integrate Django channels into my existing Django application.

Here's my routing.py:

```
from channels.routing import route

channel_routing = [
    route('websocket.receive', 'chat.consumers.ws_echo', path=r'^/chat/$'),
]
```

Here's my consumers.py:

```
def ws_echo(message):
    message.reply_channel.send({
        'text': message.content['text'],
    })
```

I am trying to create a socket by doing this:

```
ws = new WebSocket('ws://' +  window.location.host + '/chat/');

ws.onmessage = function(message) {
  alert(message.data);
};

ws.onopen = function() {
  ws.send('Hello, world');
};
```

When I run this code, I get the following error in my console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/chat/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

On my server, I get the following error:

```
HTTP GET /chat/ 404
```

Based on the error, I think that Django is giving a http connection rather than a ws connection.

Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you already define the ws_connect?. I think you need to define that function and append, the accept to make the handshaking correctly.  def ws_connect(message):
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})

Comment: I added that and still got the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with my setup was with my nginx configuration. All I had to do was add the forwarding lines and it fixed the problem.

```
location /chat { # Django Channels
            proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        }
```